# In-class member initializer fails with VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

I expected the following code to compile, but Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 gives me an error, while g++ 4.7 compiles it fine.

```
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct Settings
{
    vector<string> allowable = { "-t", "--type", "-v", "--verbosity" };
};
```

VS 2013 compile fails with:

> `'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>::vector'` : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments

If I change the member as follows then it compiles fine:

```
vector<string> allowable = vector<string> { "-t", "--type", "-v", "--verbosity" };
```

I've looked at the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html) linked from Bjarne's [FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) and I've looked at the MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) on completed C++11 features in VS 2013 but I'm still confused. Should it compile as is, or am I wrong and must specify the type twice?

Comment: `initializer_list` is terribly broken on MSVC 2013 sadly, in fact a lot of the C++11 features are a bit of a die roll on whether they work or not :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The example that you showed is perfectly valid C++, however it doesn't work for VC++2013.
- This is a known [VC++2013 bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807232/class-member-vector-initialization-list-unexpected-c-11) reported since 31/10/2013 and its status is still active.
- However, you can surmount it by doing a work-around. As [@ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) suggested, by simply putting an extra pair of curly braces you force `initializer_list<>` constructor of the `std::vector` to be evoked instead of its fill constructor, like the example below:

---

```
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   struct Settings {
     std::vector<std::string> allowable = {{"-t", "--type", "-v", "--verbosity"}};
   };

   int main() {
     Settings s;
     for (auto i : s.allowable) std::cout << i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: Because constructors are being called as though parentheses were used instead of braces, one can simply use a second set of braces to force the `initializer_list<>` constructor to be called. So `std::vector<std::string> allowable = {{ "-t", "--type", "-v", "--verbosity" }};` is a simpler workaround. +1 for finding the Connect bug.

Comment: @ildjarn thanks dude, I corrected it, your solution is simpler therefore better.