# How to write initialization list for std::map to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, initializer-list

I've tried to create std::map with the following way : 
`std::map<QString, std::shared_ptr<A> > stringToA { {QString("B"), std::shared_ptr<A>(new B())}, {QString("C"), std::shared_ptr<A>(new C())} };`
Where C & B inherited from A, I've same result with `std::make_shared<A>`.
My question is the following : how can I initialize `std::map` to `shared_ptr`, and why the code doesn't work properly?

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class A{
public:
A(){qDebug()<<"ctorA";}
~A(){qDebug()<<"dtorA";}
};

class B : public A {
public:
B(){qDebug()<<"ctorB";}
~B(){qDebug()<<"dtorB";}
};

class C : public A {
public:
C(){qDebug()<<"ctorC";}
~C(){qDebug()<<"dtorC";}
};

std::map<QString, std::shared_ptr<A> > stringToA { {QString("B"), std::shared_ptr<A>(new B())}, {QString("C"), std::shared_ptr<A>(new C())} };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug()<<"start of programm";
    return 0;

}
```

Output is the following:

```
ctorA
ctorB
ctorA
ctorC
dtorB
dtorA
start of programm
dtorC
dtorA
```

Why dtorB caled before start of programm?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your initialization is well-defined. The error is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<A>(new B())` is unsafe (can leak memory), better use `make_shared<B>()`

Comment: make_shared<B>() doesn't work because of inheritance

Comment: You're mistaken, `shared_ptr<A>` can be constructed from `shared_ptr<B>` because `B` is implicitly convertible to `A`. [demo](http://rextester.com/BYP97790)

Comment: `std::make_shared<B>()` should work just fine if your class hierarchy is the way you describe it ([see (9) here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)).

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/JHIBB93933)

Comment: I've tried with make_shared but again have same output, I see your example I dont know but my compiler behave somehow different

Comment: It seems problem with my compiler MSVC 2013 which doesn't fully support C++ 14 features.

Comment: Can you self-answer with what you discovered, ebeglary?

Comment: No, I can't I just know that MSVC 2013 have problems with initialisation list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518192/in-class-member-initializer-fails-with-vs-2013